# select statement for LINQ in selectmany

Tags: c#, linq

I have an response returned from a SOAP query that has hierarchical data with each row/field as Name/Value objects in an array as per this image:
[image: object hierarchy]

I am showing the first field 'sequnumb' but there are many fields in the Fields array.

Now I can iterate through each of these Fields array items, do a massive switch/case statement and 'flatten' the object into something i need.
But i wondered if there was a better way using linq.

What i want to have is something like this:

```
while (response.Records != null)
{
    var rows = from row in response.Records
                    from field in row.Fields
                    where field.Name == "status" && field.Value[0] != 'X'
                    select new {
                        seqnumb = from f in field where f.Name == "seqnumb" select f.Value
                    };
    foreach (var row in rows)
    {

    }
    // get new response..
}
```

Where an object with the value seqnumb = 3 (and many other parameters from Fields array) is returned.

Currently I have 'select row' as the last statement in the linq statement which i iterate through with a switch/case, which works but has a lot of code, and i would like to improve my linq understanding.

thanks for reading.

Comment: So do you want to fill in the empty block in your example with logic to build an Object of type T for each "row" in "response.Records", or do you want to replace your declaration of "rows" with a Linq expression that produces an Iterable of Object of type T? Either way, you'll need to use a constructor or factory for T.

Comment: i was wondering how to do it all in linq if possible.  Currently i am doing a foreach (row in rows){foreach (field in row.Fields){}} type iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if I'm fully grasping your description or not, but it sounds to me like this would work:

```
var fields = 
from row in response.Records
where 
    row.Fields.Any(f1 => f1.Name == "status" && f1.Value != 'X') &&
    row.Fields.Any(f2 => f2.Name == "seqnumb" && f2.Value == "3")
select(r => r.Fields);

/*
 * fields, if not null, now contains the complete fields collection
 * of the row that you appear to be interested in.
 *
 * You mentioned wanting a row that has a field named seqnumb == "3"
 * and your code also showed that you want to ensure that the fields
 * collection for that row have a field named "status" != 'X'
 *
 * You can pull--from var fields above--a list of only
 * the fields that you are interested in via something like the below
 */

List<string> fieldNamesWanted = new List<string>
    {"seqnumb", "someotherfield", "anotherfield"};

var onlyTheFieldsYouWant = 
(
    from field in fields
    where fieldNamesWanted.Any(x => x == field.Name)
    select field
).ToList();
```